# How to detect specific keyword from text in a large DB?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have had at this issue for a day now. From PHP + MYSQL angle. I but because of the amount of data, most all scripts, that I've tried have timed out.

So we have two tables:

- **People** with the row **name** - about **4000** unique entries
- **Texts** with the row **message** - about **24 000** entries

Messages have their own format, that names get put into `[]` tags, like so: `[Jenna]`.

Sadly, not all entries from **Texts** are correctly formatted. However I do have alot of names in **People**. So I want to parse trough the **Texts->message**'s and see if any **names** from **People** is matched. Of course I do not want to match `[Somename]`, since its already tagged.

Ultimately, the goal is to then do an `UPDATE` query, so the freshly matched **message** would be then formatted correctly with `[]` tag. I don't know if, this could be achieved inside the same single SQL query?!

This is a regex example on, what I want to detect and explanation on what is going on inside `preg_match_all()`: https://regex101.com/r/cQ6gK5/1

This is what I tried, as advanced MySQL is not my strongest side:

```
<?    
function GetPeople () {
    global $DB;
    $results = $DB->query("SELECT `name` FROM People");
    while ($result = $DB->fetch_array($results)) {
        $return[] = $result['name'];
    }
    return implode('|', $return);
}

$people = GetPeople();

echo '<table><tr><th>Message raw</th><th>Matches</th>';

$results = $DB->query("SELECT `message` FROM Texts WHERE `message` NOT REGEXP '\[(.+?)\]'");
while ($result = $DB->fetch_array($results)) {
    if (preg_match_all('/(?:(?:^|[\s])(' . $people . ')[\s|\n])/i', $result['message'], $matches)) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $result['message'] . '</td><td><pre>'; print_r($matches); echo '</pre></td></tr>';
    }
}

echo '</table>';
```

I have indexed out the **name** and **message** in MySQL, because I assume, that makes it easier to search. And I imagine, that all this could be done without the php matching and only with SQL query alone. Sadly, I could never get it so optimized as it should be on my own. Any help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with preg_match_all, but your regex should be `'/(?:(?:^|\s)(' . $people. ')(?=\s))/i'` so it does not consume whitespace from adjacent names. And there is no _alternation_ construct in character classes, and `\s` is a class all by itself, no need to put it in a class unless you want to combine it with some other characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT texts.message
FROM texts
JOIN people on texts.message LIKE CONCAT('%', people.name, '%');
```

This will join the two tables and then perform a like comparison based on the 'names' column in the 'people' table.

Comment: Well, it kinda works. Good starting basis at least. Thank you.